# Why are these FIRST sets not combined into a single set?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers

In Sebesta's *Concepts of Programming Languages 10th edition* on page 189 he explains the concept of $\text{FIRST}$ sets using the following example:

> $A \rightarrow aB \ | \ bAb \ | \ Bb$
>
> $B \rightarrow cB \ | \ d$
>
> The $\text{FIRST}$ sets for the RHSs of the $A$-rules are $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, and $\{c, d\}$, which are clearly disjoint.

Why aren't the first two sets combined into a single set $\{a, b\}$ instead? If $\{c, d\}$ is constructed by taking the two leftmost terminal symbols from $B$ then why don't we likewise take the two leftmost terminal symbols from $A$ into a single set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three $A$-rules, each one with its right-hand side: $aB$, $bAb$, and $Bb$. Each produces a set as its value for $FIRST$. $FIRST(aB) = \{a\}$, and $FIRST(bAb) = \{b\}$.

In its turn, $FIRST(Bb) = FIRST(B)$ (because  $B$ does not derive the empty string), and $FIRST(B) = FIRST(cB) \cup FIRST(d) = \{c\} \cup \{d\} = \{c,d\}$.

Naturally, $FIRST(A) = \{a, b, c, d\}$.

Comment: Ah ok! I get it now. Sebesta gives only a cursory mention of `FIRST` and only used logical notation to describe the set, not walk through constructing it. And no mention of `FOLLOW`, or of `PREDICT` sets in general. What you wrote makes perfect sense. Thank you.